# Drupal Multiple email accounts in site information?

Tags: drupal

I had created 4 admins in my website and i want all of them to receive the email messages. I already configured the site e-mail address in the site Information but i can only add one value in the field. is there some way i can add more email address to that field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One best way would be to create a mail group and use that address here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in Drupal but what I would do is setup an email alias/group/list for the company. site-messages@example.com and then add all their email addresses to that email. This is easy to do if you have Google Apps mail or any other robust email provider.